# Connect React components to EPI Server (Optimizely) CMS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, server-side-rendering, episerver

In my company we have:

- EPI Server (Optimizely) - .NET CMS solution for building webshop with a number of content blocks. Those content blocks can be nested
- React Library with front end components

How to tie them together without creating standalone front - end React SPA?

Initial approach was to use .cshtml templates and try to render our CMS content blocks as React components (that worked with Vue).

I have tested React.NET https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/ but was not able to render nested blocks. Also it is not actively maintained.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices - is Deprecated now.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions - I can't find any docs and examples

I'm stuck, any ideas, libs or hints about general approach?

Comment: Your block view could mount a React component without using React.NET. It depends on whether SSR (server-side rendering) is required.

Comment: @TedNyberg I am searching for a efficient and maintanable solution, so all ideas welcome. Would it work with nested blocks? How would you approach this with SSR?

Comment: There are a zillion different ways of approaching a SPA architecture with Optimizely, but you can find a lot of valuable resources here: https://www.david-tec.com/2020/05/single-page-application-spa-resources-for-building-headless-front-ends-with-episerver/